# Dynamic ArrayList fields

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an assingment for school and I am having trouble with some ArrayLists. I have an input file which has one entry at every line. This entry has an integer and up to four strings. This input file is about locations that a film is filmed. The integer is the movieID in my case and the strings are the locations. However not every film has 4 locations which means that when my program tries to load the file it returns an error because it expects 5 fields at every row and this never happens because I have movies with 1 or 2 or the locations. I use a data loader class because I have to load several different files. My other files have a specific number of entries and fields at each row so loading those isn't a problem. The load process is done by adding the file into an array list and then creating the objects needed. I know that I need the program somehow to understand the empty fields and maybe handle them dynamically, for example a movie has 3 locations so the 4th field is empty, but I haven't figured it out yet. Any suggestions? Thank you!

This is my LocationsLoader class.

```
    package dataLoader;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import dataModel.Locations;

    public class LocationsLoader extends AbstractFileLoader<Locations>{

    public int constructObjectFromRow(String[] tokens, ArrayList<Locations> locations) {

        int movieID;
        List<String> loc = new List();

        movieID = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
        loc = tokens[]; // What goes here?

        Locations l;
        l = new Locations(movieID, loc);
        locations.add(l);
        System.out.println(l);
        //System.out.println(locations.toString());
        return 0;
       }
    }
```

And this is my Locations class:

```
    package dataModel;

    public class Locations {

        private int movieID;
        private List<String> loc;

       public Locations(int otherMovieID, List<String> otherLocations) {
            this.movieID = otherMovieID;
            this.loc = otherLocations;
        }

        public int getMovieID() {
            return movieID;
        }   

        public void setMovieID(int id) {
            this.movieID = id;
        }

        public String getLocations(int index) {
            return loc.get(index);
        }
     }
  }
```

Comment: Why was your `fullDataLoad` function compressed to a single line? What type of object is `movieLoader`?

Comment: try to read a line in the input file in one String variable then apply split to it to read the values in an arrayList.

Comment: @Michael check the edit please. I just reuploaded the code.

Comment: StringTokenizer is an old class that's been kept to support old code. Use String.split() instead.

Answer (score 1):

You fill an array here

```
String[] tokens = new String[numFields];
for (int i = 0; i < numFields; i++) {
    tokens[i] = tokenizer.nextToken();
}
```

but arrays are fixed length, there's really no reason to use them if you can have fewer values. Fill a list instead.

```
List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<>();
while (tokenizer.hasNextToken()) {
    String token = tokenizer.nextToken().trim();
    if (!token.isEmpty()) {
        tokens.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
    }
}
```

In fact, I'm not sure why you would need to give the reader the number of expected tokens at all.

But as Dodgy pointed out, you might as well use String#split:

```
String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter);
```

which will yield empty Strings as well, but you can just ignore those in your  `constructObjectFromRow` function.

Comment: Using String.split() will allow you to keep using arrays (instead of List) but with a variable size.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException Agreed. Added to my answer.

Comment: Ok so I see what you say but right now I am so confused. This code that I have works just fine if I give it the right fields to expect. How am I going to split the "tokens" array? In which part of the code? @daniu

Comment: @hristoforidisc the `line.split(delimiter)` does the splitting, the resulting array contains the individual items (just as you would have after your own code). Just replace your `for`-loop with it (and you can get rid of the `StringTokenizer` bit too).

Comment: @daniu Is the edited code what you suggest? I can also delete the if block that checks the numFields and generaly delete the whole numFields variable from every function but that's another story. Even with the edited code I am able to read only the file entries that have 5 fields as I said earlier. What is wrong?

Comment: Instead of having four `locationN` fields in your class, use a `List`. Instead of methods `getLocation1` .. `getLocation4` have one method `getLocation(int index)`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException maybe something like the edited locations and locationsLoader classes? Still got few problems

Comment: Where you have `loc = tokens[];` you want to create a `List` from an array. You do that with `List<String> loc = Arrays.asList(tokens);`.

Comment: At this line List<String> loc = new List(); I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot instantiate the type List

Comment: @hristoforidisc are the `Locations`, `Directors` etc your classes as well or are you given those from the problem description? I don't see how they bring more to the mix than what a `Map<Integer, List<String>>` would. The using of which would make the code much easier, but it really depends on where it's going after. And you have to use `new ArrayList<>()`.

Comment: @hristoforidisc did you just delete the original problem? Please don't do that, this is confusing for everyone.

Comment: No I just deleted the class that after your suggestions was fixed and I did that only to help these guys and don't complicate things. I am really a beginner at this forum and I am not used to the rules yes. Sorry.